# AngularJS on-off switch

Tags: angularjs

I want a button in angularJs, that when I press it a function is called and when I press it again it does another function, like an ON-OFF switch.

I have this:

```
<a ng-click="addForm(data)" href=""> <div class="starOff" ng-class="{starOn: checkF(data)}"></div> </a>
```

I would to call another function when I click it once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you change the `ng-click` to something other than `addForm(data)`, like `handleClick(data)`, and then in your controller you can define `handleClick(data)` to call `addForm(data)` if a certain flag is already true?

Answer (score 7):

You can use ng-switch.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <div ng-switch on="selected">
        <button ng-switch-when='true' ng-click='button1()'>button1</button>
        <button ng-switch-when='false' ng-click='button2()'>button2</button>
    </div>
</div>

function Ctrl($scope) {
    $scope.selected = true;
    $scope.button1 = function () {
        //do logic for button 1
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
        console.log('btn1 clicked');
    }

    $scope.button2 = function () {
        //do logic for button 2
        $scope.selected = !$scope.selected;
        console.log('btn2 clicked');
    }
}
```

<kbd>**[Demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEbUD/)**</kbd>

Comment: I like this solution better. By having two buttons there is a nice separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using `ng-click` and `ng-class` to toggle the class.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <a ng-click="newClass=toggleClass($event)" ng-class="newClass" href="">Toggle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {
  $scope.toggleClass = function(obj) {

    if (obj.srcElement.className == 'starOn') {
      return 'starOff';
    } else if (obj.srcElement.className == 'starOff') {
      return 'starOn';
    } else {
      return 'starOn'; 
    }

  }
};
```

There are probably better ways to grab the current class name.

Here's the [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/MT56s/).

Comment: Interesting. Why have directives like `ng-class` or `angular.element`?

Comment: Oh, and I thought that because you were using `ng-class` you wanted to change the class onClick. I kinda missed the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a property instead of a call to the function `checkF()`.  Pretend the property is `mySwitch`.  When your `addForm()` is called, set `mySwitch` to *true*.

Answer (score 0):

**How To Toggle A Function Using `ng-click`**

One (of many) methods to swap between two functions when using `ng-click`. It uses a similar method to what [tnunamak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/555642/tnunamak) suggested.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="miniapp">
  <div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <a ng-click="toggle(toggled)" ng-init="toggled=false" href="">Toggle</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var $scope;
var app = angular.module('miniapp', []);

function Ctrl($scope) {

  $scope.toggle = function(toggled) {

    if (toggled == false) {
        alert('Function A');
        $scope.toggled = true;
    } else if (toggled == true) {
        alert('Function B');
        $scope.toggled = false;
    }

  }
};
```

And the [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/FqFSs/).

Answer (score 0):

You can implement it using Font-Awesome and angular js with following example

```
  <div class="onoffswitch"  >
    <input type="checkbox" name="someOnOFF" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch6" ng-model="vm.youmodelOnOff"  />
  <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch6">
          <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
           <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
     </label>
 </div>
```